# Two sample test of independent proportions with weighted data?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

In analysis of survey data, response data may often be weighted to reflect the sampling procedure or relative importance of the respondents.

For instance, a consumer survey may sample 50 respondents with 4+ years of college and 50 with less-than-four years of college, but a separate demographic data may show the prevalence of these groups are say 30% / 70% in the target market from which they are sampled.  Further, respondents may be weighted by say category purchase volume, so a respondent with 100 purchases in the last year counts 5x as someone with 20 purchases in the last year year.

This case also occurs with medical observational research with multi-level sampling by specialties, and weighting for physician patient volume and patient visit frequency.

The net result is that each respondent `[i]` has a weight `w[i]` and crosstabs shows non-integer sums of weights rather than unweighted integer counts of distinct respondents.

It seems common practice for the weights to be scaled so that the sum of weights overall equals the original unweighted sample size.

In this case, how does weighting affect testing of contingency tables for independence of sample proportions?   Does the chi-square test become more reasonable even as expected cell sizes become small because the data is not quite as lumpy and assumptions of continuity become ok?   Use or not use Yates continuity correction?

Conversely, is Fishers' Exact Test even defined or relevant for weighted non-integer frequencies?   I'm assuming rounding results to integer and using FET would be the opposite of exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, scaling the weights to sum to the sample size will mitigate the problems caused by ignoring the sampling design in the analysis.  The chi-squared test will still not be correct, and Fisher's Exact Test isn't.  (I would recommend against Yates' correction, because it's quite badly conservative)

You can do better. Rao & Scott worked out the actual sampling distribution of Pearson's chi-squared statistic back in the 1980s, and the Rao-Scott tests are implemented for survey samples in most standard statistical software (Stata, the survey package for R, SAS PROC SURVEYFREQ, the SPSS COMPLEX SURVEYS extension)